# Cukespace hooks for before/after scenario?

Tags: java, tomcat, junit, cucumber, jboss-arquillian

I'm trying out [Cukespace](https://github.com/cukespace/cukespace) with arquillian and managed Tomcat.  I need to redeploy the application for each scenarioI'm testing.

Does Cukespace provide any extensions like arquillian LoadableExtensions, which allows adding hooks to the lifecycle of test, so I can perform deploy and undeploy at each scenario?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Cukespace sends events extensions can use to integrate when lifecycle is different from a standard junit test (no @test), see
It was an answer to a question I asked in the same context:
https://github.com/cukespace/cukespace/issues/88